# What is difference between controller and libraries of codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Today in interview interviewer asked me above question.
So what is the correct answer?

Comment: A library enables certain functions that can be called from an e.g. Controller. The Controller actually calls the functions

Comment: More interesting is: What was your answer? The short answer is a controller extends the class 'CI_Controller'. Any other "library" might or might not extend another class but it won't extend `CI_Controller` or any subclass thereof.

Comment: I was kind of confused so I said that controller gets request from user,interacts with model and display data to user in form of views and libraries dont do this kind of stuff.

Comment: One way of thinking about a library is something that you want to be able to use in other applications. In other words its not specific to the application you are creating. For example a library which processes credit card transactions. You would then take that library and extend it for the needs of your application. But the library itself is neutral.

Comment: Otherwise thats a good definition for a controller :-)

Comment: I would say that a controller is a class for only one page or thing, while a library is a class which is broadly used in the application or across other applications.

Comment: @akkif444, Your answer is pretty good as it shows you understand the basic idea of the controller's roll in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

A controller is the one who has all the functions that are user defined. it extends CI_Controller which has functions that you can use to be able to make a function.

Libraries are those which you load to help you make an easier task. Libraries are also like controllers, but really just load one thing. For example, csv import library, you load this in the controller to help you import csv's into the website using the functions there.